# How to support UIStackView in versions below iOS9

Tags: ios, swift

UIStackView is new feature in iOS9. If my app also support iOS8 or below version. Then how i can work  with UIStackview?

Comment: It will not support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/tomvanzummeren/TZStackView

It has the same API as UIStackView, so will be easy to move over to UIStackView once you're ready to drop pre-iOS 9 devices.